# Why is BuLi a better nucleophile than base?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, organometallic-compounds

In Carey, Sundberg Advanced Organic Chemistry it is written:

> The relative slowness of the abstraction of protons from carbon acids by organolithium
>   reagents is probably also due to the compact character of the carbon-lithium
>   clusters. Since the electrons associated with the carbanion are tightly associated with
>   the cluster of lithium cations, some activation energy is required to break the bond
>   before the carbanion can act as a base. This kinetic sluggishness of organometallic
>   compounds as bases permits important reactions in which the organometallic species
>   acts as a nucleophile in preference to functioning as a strong base.

Won't the same reasons apply for nucleophilic displacement? Compactness of the aggregates should affect nucleophilicity, too. So why will BuLi add to a carbonyl instead of deprotonating the alpha carbon atom?

Comment: tBuLi and LDA? Both organolithiums that act solely as bases (or at least never as nucleophiles)

Comment: They act so because of they are bulky. I am more interestsed in BuLi and similar organolithiums.

Comment: 'Why are organolithiums better as nucleophiles than bases'    Maybe update your title and question to be more specific. The statement isn't really a general one other than n-Buli

Comment: Edited. Hope that it is more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a trick question, which explains why the first sentence from the book takes so many precautions. It is very difficult to provide a general explanation because there are many factors influencing the result.

1. **Solvent**: the solvent is extremely important in such reactions. It
   plays an important role in the order of oligomerization of the
   organolithium reagent; monomers, dimers, tetramers or polymers. Of
   course, the reactivity is really different.
2. **Co-solvent**: a co-solvent like HMPT or TMEDA can drastically change
   the course of the reaction by changing the order of oligomerization.
3. **Temperature**: it is well known that n-butyllithium is a very strong
   base at low temperatures (<-60°C) but will become a good nucleophile
   at higher temperatures. It can even open a THF ring.
4. **Thermodynamic or kinetic control**: organolithium compounds are
   usually used under kinetic control, but...
5. **HSAB**: how the oligomerization affects the hardness/softness of the
   base and its nucleophilicity?
6. **3D shape** of the organolithium compound: it greatly influences the
   shape and order of oligomers.
7. ...

So now you feel completely depressed, I can try to answer your question. I think that a key factor is actually that in a cluster (dimer, tetramer and so on), charges are more diluted which enhances the nucleophilic behavior. Also, the geometry of the cluster and of its 3D-complex with the substrate could explain why a reaction is favored over the other.

Comment: Great answer! :D I concluded that oligomeriation softens the organolithium.